# Slim micro framework,why I can't insert the record to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, api, slim

I currently follow [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/) which about creating an api using Slim.
So I try to make a register system using the same code.

Here is my function of register function inside DBHandler.php

```
 public function createUser ($username,$email,$password){
    require_once 'PassHash.php';
    //check whether email exist or not
    if(!$this->isUserEmailExisted($email)) {
        //hash the password
        $password_hash = PassHash::hash($password);
        //generate api_key
        $api_key = $this->generateApiKey();
        //insert query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password_hash,api_key,status)VALUES(:username,:email,:password,:api_key,1)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$username,$email,$password_hash,$api_key);

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if ($result) {
            return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
        } else {
            return USER_CREATE_FAILED;
        }
    } else{
        return USER_ALREADY_EXISTED;
    }
}
```

I just check the insert query my times, but I don't know what is the problem for this.

```
//insert query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password_hash,api_key,status)VALUES(:username,:email,:password,:api_key,1)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$username,$email,$password_hash,$api_key);
```

The result is always this

> {
>   "error": true,
>   "message": "Oops! An error occurred while registering"
>   }

And my query parameter is

> username=abc email=abc@gmail.com password=123456

which should be get this result of successful register. But it keeps come of the result of error which unsuccessfully insert to database.

Here is the function call in my index.php

```
$app->post('/register', function() use ($app) {
    // check for required params
    verifyRequiredParams(array('username', 'email', 'password'));

    $response = array();

    // reading post params
    $username = $app->request->post('username');
    $email = $app->request->post('email');
    $password = $app->request->post('password');

    // validating email address
    validateEmail($email);

    $db = new DbHandler();
    $res = $db->createUser($username, $email, $password);

    if ($res == USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "You are successfully registered";
        echoRespnse(201, $response);
    } else if ($res == USER_CREATE_FAILED) {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred while registereing";
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    } else if ($res == USER_ALREADY_EXISTED) {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Sorry, this email already existed";
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    }
});
```

Here is my database

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password_hash` text NOT NULL,
  `api_key` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='all user data ';
```

I just try my best to check all the expect,and searching for all question about Slim,but my knowledge and experience is still very limited,so I still dont get what are my mistake,any guideline is well appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I make a try to include `created_at` in the query and make `$status=1` and bind_param in the statement,but the output is still the same

```
// Generating API key
            $api_key = $this->generateApiKey();
            $status = 1;
            // insert query
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, email, password_hash, api_key, status,created_at) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,NOW())");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $username, $email, $password_hash, $api_key,$status);

            $result = $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->close();
```

@Dusan Jovanov,I make a change in my code,can you see am I doing right??
Inside my `createUser()` method

```
// Check for successful insertion
        if ($result) {
            // User successfully inserted
            return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
        } else {
            $error = $stmt->error_list;
            // Failed to create user
            return $error;

        }
    } else {
        // User with same email already existed in the db
        return USER_ALREADY_EXISTED;
    }
```

In '/register' call back

```
     else if ($res == $error) {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] =$error;

        echoRespnse(200, $response);
```

Am I doing what you mention??

Cause I getting this error

[image: error after following Dusan Jovanov]
Sorry cause I still new in php..still learning..thanks for help

Comment: Did you try to provide a value for `created_at ` ? According to your database schema, this value cannot be null and you don't provide it in your createUser function.

Comment: I make the changes,but the output still the same.I at `NOW()` and `created_at` in the query.and `$status=1` instead of 1 inside the query

Comment: print out the value of `$stmt->error` or `$stmt->error_list`

Comment: @DusanJovanov where can I get the value ya??I mean the result,cause I access this URL http://localhost/abc/v1/index.php/ it state the page not found.So i dont know where to get the result print out...

Comment: well, make `createuser()` return that value and then in your `'/register'` callback function `echorespnse($res,200)` or something like that..

Comment: ` if ($result) {
                // User successfully inserted
                return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
            } else {
                $error = $stmt->error_list;
                // Failed to create user
                return $error;

            }`

Comment: am i doing right?Cause I not so sure for what you mean

Comment: @DusanJovanov sir I make an edit in my question,can you please give a look for what I doing is it right?

Comment: No, just comment this `if ($result) {
            return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
        } else {
            return USER_CREATE_FAILED;
        }` and write this `return $stmt->error` instead

Comment: And in `$app->post('register',function(){  });` write `echorespnse($res,200)` after this `$res = $db->createUser($username, $email, $password);`

Comment: @DusanJovanov I still having the same error that I show about,after I do the step that you state out..

Comment: I don't know man, it's some weird error with some library slim uses. But I see that you're using Slim 2, and Slim 3 is the newest version. Why don't you have a look at this [user guide](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/) and follow the tutorials here, especially First Application.

Comment: @DusanJovanov ok thanks bro..thanks for your help..I try to figure it out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I just solved this problem.I just make a very silly mistake.
In fact this code is don't have any problem,but I just need to make the request in the 'Data form' section instead of at the 'address' section

Instead of make the query here,
[image: not insert here]

I should make my query here,the 'Data from' part in Advance Rest Client
  [image: should make the query here]

After doing this,I just solve my problem
I am a beginner and I make a silly mistake,hope can solve same problem for the next person who follow this useful tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Answer (score 0):

`Status` column type is `int` so try binding the parameter this way:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $username, $email, $password_hash, $api_key, $status);
```

Comment: I just try..but it seem still having the same output